# Cannot convert from method group to string when reading file C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, hash

I got this software that scans a file that I select and then computes the MD5 hash.

I am trying to compare the computed MD5 hash with a list of hashes from a dictionary to see if it matches, and if it does it says something.

How do I programmatically add the dictionary.txt to my code.

I tried using the `File.OpenRead()` but I am getting an error saying

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Did I miss something?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace MD5_Hash_Compare
{
    public partial class lblTitle : Form
    {
        public lblTitle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string MD5HashFile(string fn)
        {
            byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(fn));
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
        }

        private Stream TestStream()
        {
            Stream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\PathToDictionary");
            return fs;
        }

        public string GetMD5(string file)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(TestStream))
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
        }

        private void lblTitle_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void scanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = txtFilePath.Text;

            //if there is something in the textbox to scan we need to make sure that its doing it.
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
              // ... report problem to user.
              return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Scan Complete");
            }

            hashDisplay.Text = MD5HashFile(path);
        }

        private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFilePath.Text = (ofd.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `GetMD5` function, you do this

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(TestStream))
```

`TestStream` is a function, so you need to add parentheses to call it.

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(TestStream()))
```

Comment: So I dont need the " return Encoding.Default.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)); " at all?

Comment: Yes you need it... but you need to add `()` next to `TestStream` in the line above.

Comment: Thats what I did and it confused me because I got this error.
" cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'string' "

Comment: Not sure if you got notified, couldnt edit my comment

Comment: Your `TestStream()` method already returns a `Stream`. `File.OpenRead` is for creating a new `Stream` which is not needed here because `TestStream()` is already a Stream. You can replace the `using(var stream=.....` line by `var stream = TestStream();`

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark my answer as correct by clicking on the green tick.